# Is this a well founded inductive type? Can I express this in Coq?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-types, coq, inductive-datatypes

the standard List type in Coq can be expressed as:

```
Inductive List (A:Set) : Set :=
  nil : List A
| cons : A -> List A -> List A.
```

as I understand, W-type express a well-founded tree of elements of this type. so, what if `nil` is not qualified by `A`? i.e. we have:

> for all `A: Set` `nil : List A`

instead of

> for all `A: Set` `nil A: List A`

is this a correct W-type? can I express this in Coq?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to construct. In the standard List definition, nil isn't exactly qualified by A, it has type "List A", so "nil A" isn't a thing it's just "nil" and it has type "List A" (for any A, because it's polymorphic). In essence the change you suggest is in fact what you already have. Or have I missed the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood why `A` stands there in the definition of list.

Let us first look at how we might define lists of booleans:

```
Inductive ListBool : Set :=
  | nilBool : ListBool
  | consBool : bool -> ListBool -> ListBool.
```

And here is how we might define lists of natural numbers:

```
Inductive ListNat : Set :=
  | nilNat : ListNat
  | consNat : nat -> ListNat -> ListNat.
```

As you can see the `nilBool` and `nilNat` are constants that do *not* depend on any parameters. It is boring to define lists of booleans, lists of natural numbers, lists of lists of booleans, etc. Coq allows a *parametrized* definition of lists in which the `List` type itself takes a parameter `A` as input, to give lists of elements of type `A`. This is defined as you wrote:

```
Inductive List (A : Set) : Set :=
  | nil : List A
  | cons : A -> List A -> List A.
```

In the `nil` clause we have `List A`. Here `A` is the argument to `List`, it is not an argument to `nil`. If we wrote just `List` then Coq would ask "list of *what*"? For a similar reason the `cons` constructor has two occurences of `List A`.

Let me put it another way. The type of `ListNat` is `Set`. The type of `List` is `Set -> Set`. So we have to apply `List` to a set before we get a list.

Comment: Thanks. I have some misunderstood by W-type (I still do not understand...), and I have noticed that my version of `nil` is not uniquely typed...